# Unit/integration tests that verify the properties or configurations

Tags: java, testing, spring-boot, yaml, integration-testing

Does it make sense to write unit/integration tests that verify the properties or configurations, since any medium to highly complex applications include a lot of configurations (via YAML or properties files)?

Many of these configurations derive the run time behaviour even if they are used by the underlying libraries or frameworks. Would it be a sensible idea to verify that the configurations are correctly used at runtime?

One pro-argument is since there is no compiler safety, we need to somehow verify if the configurations are dictating the behaviour correctly.

The con argument is, are we verifying the underlying frameworks implementation?

Testing just the configuration file might not be enough as it does not guarantee if the configuration will be correctly employed at runtime (there could be typos or other similar mistakes).

Comment: Im just working on something write now which has it's own properties file for `src\test\resources`... dont think it would give so much value to verify that, given that run time configuration will be different

Answer (score 3):

No. Unit tests will tell you what works in the test harness, which is—and should be—different from what is in production.

You hit the nail on the head when you said you want to *verify* the configuration. Testing and verification are two entirely different things. If you have a way to verify the runtime configuration in production, it will also help you diagnose runtime misbehavior.

There are lots of ways to verify the runtime configuration. The simplest and best is logging (e.g. "2016-09-24 10:13:00 connecting to http://my-configured-server.example.com to get user token"). Don't just dump the configuration to the log file-- that's not end-to-end verification-- sprinkle configuration details into log messages.

Configuration issues are often all-or-nothing; if you don't get the configuration just right, nothing happens and you don't know why. (This is especially true with functional programming.) Logging can tell you not only what the configuration is, but at what moment the configuration fails.

There are other clever ways to sprinkle configuration details into the runtime. For example, attaching verbose runtime details to error messages, especially email where you have more room than in logs. Or a debug mode where hovering over a UI element tells you the class and other facts about that element.

Integration tests (the components work when plugged together) and smoke tests (*some* complete configuration does *something right*) can be important-- I would say necessary if you deploy without manual testing-- but they are no substitute for runtime verification.

Comment: Depending on what configuration are we talking about, automated functional smoke tests that run right after you deploy to production can "indirectly" tell you that the configuration is right, because the system can perform critical use cases without errors.

Comment: Good point, Mauri. Tests should answer the question "what should you be afraid of?" If a change you check into version control can trigger a broken deployment, you need to find a way to test it—because you should be afraid of that. If there's a manual step in your deployment process whereby someone (e.g. a test engineer) will instantly notice that the code won't run, adding a smoke test is optional, since the worst you have to fear is embarrassment.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty reasonable IMHO, especially when talking ever growing virtualization. In one of the previous projects I was involved - a mSOA platform, which supported (back then) hundreds of web sites with ease, we found out that most of the issues were due to exactly

> configurations are correctly used at runtime

The [Orchard](http://www.orchardproject.net/) recepies were messed up a lot of the the times, as well. So a point for [Docker containers](https://www.docker.com/). It is pretty much straightforward to test the infrastructure and its configuration your product/service is using. I've used successfully [serverspec](http://serverspec.org/).